# How to pass select/dropdown value to form 2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass the selected dropdown value to another form.

**Form 1**:

```
<form role="form" action="form2.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group select one-third">
        <label>destination</label>
        <select name="destination">
            <option selected>&nbsp; Choose a destination</option>
            <optgroup label="Country 1">
            <option value="Des 1">Des 1</option>
            <option value="Des 2">Des 2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Country 2">
            <option value="Des 3">Des 3</option>
            <option value="Des 4">Des 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Form 2**:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group select one-third">
        <label>destination</label>
        <select name="destination"/>
            <option selected>&nbsp; Choose a destination</option>
            <optgroup label="Country 1">
            <option value="Des 1">Des 1</option>
            <option value="Des 2">Des 2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Country 2">
            <option value="Des 3">Des 3</option>
            <option value="Des 4">Des 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried with `value="<?php echo $_GET['vertrek']; ?>"` but this doesn't work. Can I do it without using jquery?  How can I pass the selected dropdown value to form 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if two forms in same page?

Comment: no both on another page with a submit button @Sathish

Comment: no I didn't find a solution @Sathish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pre-select an option in dropdown you can use

```
<option value='the_value' <?php ($_GET['destination']=='the_value')?"selected":""?> >Text to be displayed</option>
```

This will check whether the selected value (from form one) matches with the value of an option, if yes, that option will be selected.

**Form1.php**

```
<form role="form" action="form2.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group select one-third">
        <label>destination</label>
        <select name="destination">
            <option selected>&nbsp; Choose a destination</option>
            <optgroup label="Country 1">
            <option value="Des 1">Des 1</option>
            <option value="Des 2">Des 2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Country 2">
            <option value="Des 3">Des 3</option>
            <option value="Des 4">Des 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
<div><input type='submit' value='Submit'/></div>
</form>
```

**Form 2.php**

```
<?php 
$selected_option = "";
if(isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)){
    $selected_option = $_GET['destination'];
}
?>
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group select one-third">
        <label>destination</label>
        <select name="destination"> <1-- removed a back slash here -->
            <option selected>&nbsp; Choose a destination</option>
            <optgroup label="Country 1">
            <option value="Des 1" <?php echo ($selected_option =='Des 1')?"Selected":"";?>>Des 1</option>
            <option value="Des 2" <?php echo ($selected_option =='Des 2')?"Selected":"";?>>Des 2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Country 2">
            <option value="Des 3" <?php echo ($selected_option =='Des 3')?"Selected":"";?>>Des 3</option>
            <option value="Des 4" <?php echo ($selected_option =='Des 4')?"Selected":"";?>>Des 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to submit the first form to get values on another page.

You should have a submit button on the first form. I have edited my answer. Please check it

Comment: I know, I have also input fields and I can pass the data of the input fields with 'value="<?php echo $_GET['nameinputfield']; ?>"' but for the dropdown I can't find an solution @ash_8247

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it now. 

There was a backslash on the line  <select name="destination"/> in your form2.php. May be that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First You remove the slash from `<select/>` in form 2

then it's not working, just try it,

**Form.php**

```
<form role="form" action="form1.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group select one-third">
        <label>destination</label>
        <select name="destination">
            <option selected>&nbsp; Choose a destination</option>
            <optgroup label="Country 1">
            <option value="Des 1">Des 1</option>
            <option value="Des 2">Des 2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Country 2">
            <option value="Des 3">Des 3</option>
            <option value="Des 4">Des 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**form1.php**

```
<?php 
$des = '';
if(isset($_GET['destination'])){ $des = $_GET['destination'];
} ?>
<form role="form" action="form2.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group select one-third">
        <label>destination</label>
        <select name="destination">
            <option>&nbsp; Choose a destination</option>
            <optgroup label="Country 1">
            <option value="Des 1" <?php if($des == "Des 1"){ echo "selected";} ?>>Des 1</option>
            <option value="Des 2" <?php if($des == "Des 2"){ echo "selected";} ?>>Des 2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Country 2">
            <option value="Des 3" <?php if($des == "Des 3"){ echo "selected";} ?>>Des 3</option>
            <option value="Des 4" <?php if($des == "Des 4"){ echo "selected";} ?>>Des 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

This will help to achieve what you want!!

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery (client side):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1 [name='destination']").change(function(){
        $("#form2 [name='destination']").val($(this).val())
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZVanG/dLgpozw8/)

Comment: does this also work when form2 is on another page? @wZVanG

Comment: @Can No, this only works on the client side if there are 2 forms on same page, but this I think is an issue of PHP